# Hudson Pre-Release: 401 HTTP error when attempting kforge pull

Tags: ros, kforge, pre-release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to run a Hudson pre-install on the 'gestures' stack. Hudson's console output is at http://build.willowgarage.com/job/prerelease_unstable_gestures_lucid_i386/2/console.

The salient part seems to be this HTTP 401 error that prevents Hudson from pulling the stack out of kforge into a stack overlay:

```
------------------  Begin Excerpt --------------------------
Install the stacks to test from source.
=========================================
Failed to execute 'rosinstall --rosdep-yes stack_overlay /opt/ros/unstable stack_overlay.rosinstall'
=========================================
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/install_dir/stack_overlay/gestures/.git/
rosinstall operating on /tmp/install_dir/stack_overlay from specifications in rosinstall files  /opt/ros/unstable,         stack_overlay.rosinstall
Installing https://kforge.ros.org/gestures/gestures master to /tmp/install_dir/stack_overlay/gestures

=========================================
error: The requested URL returned error: 401 while accessing https://kforge.ros.org/gestures/gestures/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
ERROR: Failed to install tree '/tmp/install_dir/stack_overlay/gestures'
 Checkout of https://kforge.ros.org/gestures/gestures version master into /tmp/install_dir/stack_overlay/gestures failed.
------------ End Excerpt -------------
```

401 is 'user authorization required'. Do I need to open the kforge project somehow?

thanks!

Andreas

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27981/hudson-pre-release:-401-http-error-when-attempting-kforge-pull/) by [paepcke](https://answers.ros.org/users/952/paepcke/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2012-02-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The default behavior for Kforge is for a project to be private. You need to add the user "Visitor" as a "Friend"-level user for the project repositories to be publicly accessible.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2012-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [paepcke](https://answers.ros.org/users/952/paepcke/) on 2012-02-22**:
Raised Visitor role from 'Visitor' to 'Friend.' Error has changed: http://build.willowgarage.com//job/prerelease_unstable_gestures_oneiric_i386/3/. Salient:Host key verification failed.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedlyClone of 'ssh://vcs@kforge.ros.org/gestures/gesture_arm_service' into s

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-02-22**:
You need to set the checkout to pull from the https url not the ssh url.

**Comment by [paepcke](https://answers.ros.org/users/952/paepcke/) on 2012-02-22**:
Did set it to https for the stack (see original msg). The pkgs are git submodules. Guess stack is pulled w/ https, then submodules are attempted via ssh. As you say. that can't work. Will see how to control that.